# Google Analytics 4 PDF report does not show all data

Tags: google-analytics, reporting, google-analytics-4

I am a web developer, and I recently created a new property in Google Analytics 4, this was the first time.  My other client's properties are in the old GA, and each month I send them a pageviews and traffic acquisition report.

Trying to recreate those two old reports, I can see on the screen basically the same information, but trying to export it into PDF, data is lost.

When I take these steps:

- Home
- Go to `Page and Screens` panel and press the `View pages and screens`
- Press the share button along the top right
- Select `Download File`
- Select `Download PDF`

Open the PDF and it showing about a half the data I see on the screen. So, for example, if I have only 10 rows showing on the screen, that is all that is in the report.  On my screen I can see all the columns of data, but on the report, it only shows what it can in the portrait page of the PDF and about half of the columns are not shown.

Is there a way to easily send this information to my client in Google Analytics 4?